# В чем разница между mysqli_real_escape_string и htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php

Добрый день, все же не очень понятна разница между `mysqli_real_escape_string` и `htmlspecialchars`.

Ведь когда при вставке в базу данных, с использованием какого-нибудь поддельного sql запроса, используются кавычки, то они будут преобразовываться `htmlspecialchars` и опасность будет также нейтрализована.

Тогда в чем смысл `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Comment: @ariman, а что, в базу вставляют только HTML?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` хахаха, в каких ещё языках есть глобальные процедуры с такими именами! =)

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev [вы, наверное, не поверите](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html)

Comment: @Etki ! поражён

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_real_escape_string  экранирует кавычки и пару других управляющих символов.
htmlspecialchars  заменяет спецсимволы html. Например:
Если в html станице написать `<b>Hello</b>` то на экране будет **Hello**, а если написать `&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;` то на экране будет буквально `<b>Hello</b>`.
То есть < сменится на &lt; , а > на &gt;
 Нужно для того, чтобы пользователь во всяких комментах и т.д. не смог буквально верстать.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте доки, там всё написано:

[mysqli real escape string](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

[htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)